MIMO channel Shannon Capacity
How do i add the capacity of a MIMO link with NR=2 and NT=4
clear all

clc

%Shannon capacity

snr=0;

for i = 1:10

    snr = snr +2;

    c=(log(1+10^(snr/10)))/log(2);

    x(i)=snr;

    y(i)=c;

end

figure

plot(x,y,'-','LineWidth',1.5)

hold on

% capacity of MIMO Link with NR=2, NT=2

NR=2;

rand('state',456321)

snr=0;

for i=1:10;

snr=snr+2;

    for j=1:10000;

        c(j)=(NR*log(1+(10^(snr/10))*abs(normrnd(0,1)))/log(2));

    end

    yy(i)=mean(c);

    xx(i)=snr;

end

plot(xx,yy,':','LineWidth',1.5)

% capacity of MIMO Link with NR=3, NT=3

NR=3;

rand('state',456321)

snr=0;

for i=1:10;

    snr=snr+2;

    for j=1:10000;

        c(j)=(NR*log(1+(10^(snr/10))*abs(normrnd(0,1)))/log(2));

    end

    yy(i)=mean(c);

    xx(i)=snr;

end

plot(xx,yy,'-.','LineWidth',1.5)

% capacity of MIMO Link with NR=4, NT=4

NT=4;

rand('state',456321)

snr=0;

for i=1:10;

    snr=snr+2;

    for j=1:10000;

        c(j)=(NT*log(1+(10^(snr/10))*abs(normrnd(0,1)))/log(2));

    end

    yy(i)=mean(c);

    xx(i)=snr;

end

plot(xx,yy,'--','LineWidth',1.5)



plot(xx,yy,'-<','LineWidth',1.5)

xlabel('SNR(dB)')

ylabel('Capacity (bit/s/Hz)')

grid on

legend('Shannon Capacity','MIMO, NT=NR=2','MIMO, NT=NR=3','MIMO, NT=NR=4',2)

title('MIMO Capacity')

print -deps -tiff -r300 capmimo


